# Copy a Numpy 1D array to a Python List Fast

Tags: numpy

I need to Copy a large Numpy float32 1D array (Think 1 million elements) to a Python List Fast.

Doing numpyarray.tolist() takes almost 0.5 seconds. I could write a C++ wrapper to do this and do memcpy but it seems convoluted for something so simple.

Is there a way I can do a simple copy/conversion.

Comment: What if you split the list on several threads/processes to convert to list and then stitch the full list in the main process? Would in this case the time still be worse?

Comment: Why do you think you could do better?  `tolist` is already compiled code.  It's certainly fast compared to `list(arr)`.  Do you understand how a `numpy` array data storage differs from Python list?  (and why would `memcpy` help?)